# SiriKit INPayBillIntentHandling - Siri says, "I wish I could, but <App> hasn't set that up with me yet."

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sirikit, ios10.3

I'm integrating **Sirikit**, Bill Payment using the intent:

`INPayBillIntentHandling` (which was released recently in **iOS 10.3+**, 27 Mar 2017).

Apple Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents/inpaybillintenthandling).

> *Note: I'm using Obj-C Language, XCode 8.3, Device iPhone 6S with iOS 10.3 & Demo Project iOS Deployment target is iOS 10.3 AND also enabled the Siri
>   when asked the permission for the first time and also verified that In
>   Settings, Siri is enabled.*

When I launch the app on device and say "Bill Payment using DemoApp", Siri says *"I wish I could, but  DemoApp hasn't set that up with me yet"*

Please help me. Thanks in Advance!

So far I did the following steps:

1) Create a Demo Xcode project

2) In Main App Capabilities, Enabled Siri.

3) Added Sirikit extension using

> File -> New -> Add Target -> Intent Extension -> Next ->Add
>   ProductName and say Finish
>
> Note: I've disabled the Sirikit UI Extension.

4) In Main AppDelegate added the following:

```
#import <Intents/Intents.h>
    [INPreferences requestSiriAuthorization:^(INSiriAuthorizationStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Siri Authorization status...%ld", status);
    }];
```

5) In Main app Info.plist, added key `NSSiriUsageDescription` with usage description

6) In IntentExtension, Info.plist, `NSExtension->IntentsSupported->added key INPayBillIntent`

7) In IntentHandler.m, added all the delegate methods for INPayBillIntentHandling

```
@interface IntentHandler () <INPayBillIntentHandling>

@end

@implementation IntentHandler

- (id)handlerForIntent:(INIntent *)intent {
    // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
    // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.

    return self;
}

- (void)confirmPayBill:(INPayBillIntent *)intent
            completion:(void (^)(INPayBillIntentResponse *response))completion NS_SWIFT_NAME(confirm(payBill:completion:)) {
    NSLog(@"\n%s", __func__);
    INPayBillIntentResponse *response = [[INPayBillIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INPayBillIntentResponseCodeSuccess userActivity:nil];
    completion(response);
}
- (void)handlePayBill:(INPayBillIntent *)intent
          completion:(void (^)(INPayBillIntentResponse *response))completion NS_SWIFT_NAME(handle(payBill:completion:)) {
    NSLog(@"\n%s", __func__);
    NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:NSStringFromClass([INPayBillIntent class])];

    INPayBillIntentResponse *response = [[INPayBillIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INPayBillIntentResponseCodeReady userActivity:userActivity];
    completion(response);

}
- (void)resolveBillPayeeForPayBill:(INPayBillIntent *)intent
                    withCompletion:(void (^)(INBillPayeeResolutionResult *resolutionResult))completion NS_SWIFT_NAME(resolveBillPayee(forPayBill:with:)) {
    NSLog(@"\n%s", __func__);

    INSpeakableString *speakableStr = [[INSpeakableString alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"XYZ Bill" spokenPhrase:@"XYZ Bill" pronunciationHint:@"XYZ Bill"];
    INSpeakableString *speakableStr1 = [[INSpeakableString alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"XYZ Bill Payments" spokenPhrase:@"XYZ Payments" pronunciationHint:@"XYZ Bills"];

    INBillPayee *billPayee = [[INBillPayee alloc] initWithNickname:speakableStr number:@"10112122112" organizationName:speakableStr1];

    INBillPayeeResolutionResult *finalResult = [INBillPayeeResolutionResult successWithResolvedBillPayee:billPayee];

    completion(finalResult);
}
- (void)resolveFromAccountForPayBill:(INPayBillIntent *)intent
                      withCompletion:(void (^)(INPaymentAccountResolutionResult *resolutionResult))completion NS_SWIFT_NAME(resolveFromAccount(forPayBill:with:)) {
    NSLog(@"\n%s", __func__);
    INSpeakableString *speakableStr2 = [[INSpeakableString alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"john.smith" spokenPhrase:@"john.smith" pronunciationHint:@"john.smith"];
    INSpeakableString *speakableStr3 = [[INSpeakableString alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"" spokenPhrase:@"" pronunciationHint:@"organisation"];

    INPaymentAccount *fromAccount = [[INPaymentAccount alloc] initWithNickname:speakableStr2 number:@"10112122112" accountType:INAccountTypeCredit organizationName:speakableStr3];


    INPaymentAccountResolutionResult *finalResult = [INPaymentAccountResolutionResult successWithResolvedPaymentAccount:fromAccount];

    completion(finalResult);

}
- (void)resolveTransactionAmountForPayBill:(INPayBillIntent *)intent
                            withCompletion:(void (^)(INPaymentAmountResolutionResult *resolutionResult))completion NS_SWIFT_NAME(resolveTransactionAmount(forPayBill:with:)) {
    NSLog(@"\n%s", __func__);

    INCurrencyAmount *currencyAmt = [[INCurrencyAmount alloc] initWithAmount:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100"] currencyCode:@"784"];

    INPaymentAmount *transactionAmt = [[INPaymentAmount alloc] initWithAmountType:INAmountTypeAmountDue amount:currencyAmt];

    INPaymentAmountResolutionResult *finalResult = [INPaymentAmountResolutionResult successWithResolvedPaymentAmount:transactionAmt];

    completion(finalResult);

}
- (void)resolveTransactionScheduledDateForPayBill:(INPayBillIntent *)intent
                                  withCompletion:(void (^)(INDateComponentsRangeResolutionResult *resolutionResult))completion NS_SWIFT_NAME(resolveTransactionScheduledDate(forPayBill:with:)) {

    completion([INDateComponentsRangeResolutionResult notRequired]);

}
- (void)resolveTransactionNoteForPayBill:(INPayBillIntent *)intent
                          withCompletion:(void (^)(INStringResolutionResult *resolutionResult))completion NS_SWIFT_NAME(resolveTransactionNote(forPayBill:with:)) {
    NSLog(@"\n%s", __func__);
    INStringResolutionResult *finalResult = [INStringResolutionResult successWithResolvedString:@"Bill Payment"];

    completion(finalResult);
}
- (void)resolveBillTypeForPayBill:(INPayBillIntent *)intent
                  withCompletion:(void (^)(INBillTypeResolutionResult *resolutionResult))completion NS_SWIFT_NAME(resolveBillType(forPayBill:with:)) {
    NSLog(@"\n%s", __func__);
    INBillTypeResolutionResult *finalResult = [INBillTypeResolutionResult successWithResolvedValue:INBillTypeElectricity];

    completion(finalResult);

}
- (void)resolveDueDateForPayBill:(INPayBillIntent *)intent
                  withCompletion:(void (^)(INDateComponentsRangeResolutionResult *resolutionResult))completion NS_SWIFT_NAME(resolveDueDate(forPayBill:with:)) {
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
    completion([INDateComponentsRangeResolutionResult notRequired]);
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: [INPreferences requestSiriAuthorization:^(INSiriAuthorizationStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Siri Authorization status...%ld", status);
    }];


Does this print authorized?

Comment: @Cherry_thia Yes it is printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, and is found on the following line:

```
INCurrencyAmount *currencyAmt = [[INCurrencyAmount alloc] initWithAmount:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100"] currencyCode:@"784"];
```

to

```
INCurrencyAmount *currencyAmt = [[INCurrencyAmount alloc] initWithAmount:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100"] currencyCode:@"USD"];
```

Swift 3.0

```
let currencyAmmount = INCurrencyAmount(amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "100"), currencyCode: "USD")
```

You are using an incorrect currency format with causes Siri to throw this message.

Comment: i dont get this solution. How would this solve the problem?

Comment: Take a look at the following on the code lines above : currencyCode:@"784"]; The currency code is incorrect, it should be currencyCode:@"USD"]; 784 is not a currency code.

Comment: yea, but that fix doesnt fix OP question

Answer (score 0):

Try it on iOS 11 beta version. I am trying using swift on iOS 11 beta 5, it is a lot more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the handler(for intent: INIntent) function, the App info.plist and intent extension plist have the right supported intents.